# Cause `less` to exit with a non-zero status code?

Tags: less, user-interface, exit-status

I would like to have the following command structure:

```
command && check-status | less && followup-command
```

This would pause the execution while the user interacted with `less`. How can the user force `less` to exit with a non-zero status to prevent `followup-command` from running?

I am currently using `less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the simple case, you can ask `less` not to handle SIGINT, then <kbd>Control-C</kbd> will kill it and the exit code will be non-zero. Do this with option `-K`.

```
command && check-status | less -K && followup-command
```

---

As a workaround for older versions of less, you can do something like

```
command && bash -c 'trap "exit 1" int;check-status | less -K;' && followup-command
```

If you don't have `-K`, omit it, but you'll have to signal and then type quit too.

Comment: `less -K` still returns a 0 exit code on ctrl-c for me. v418 on mac and v436 on linux. `less -K test; echo $? => 0`

Comment: that's sad. it's ok on a v458 and v481 for me.The man page for `-K` explicitly says *exit ...(with status 2)*. Does yours?

Comment: man only says `Causes  less  to  exit  immediately` > http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/news.443.html

Comment: I've added a workaround for an older less.

Comment: Note that the `^C` will also kill `check-status` if it's not finished already.

Comment: Terminating `check-status` is an acceptable and preferred result of killing `less`, in my use case.