# Is it possible to "coax" arbitrary core *nix utilities into returning a non-zero exit status even when successful?

Tags: bash, shell, exit-status

I am running bash scripts and executing bash commands on remote systems using Connectwise Automate (formerly LabTech). These systems are both Linux and MacOS. Connectwise Automate (CWA) has some peculiar behavior with regards to *nix systems, wherein if a command or expression exits with a status code of 0 all output, regardless of stream (stdout or stderr), is replaced with the word "OK". When a non-0 exit status is returned the output is properly displayed in the CWA's remote terminal and script output. I have not received definitive confirmation that the output replacement behavior is based on exit code, however I believe it to be highly likely.

For a simplistic example, `echo "Test"` returns `OK`, whereas `ls ./no/such/directory` yields the appropriate exception. This is a long-standing issue with CWA and working with the vendor yields no workarounds or positive results without piping the command output to a file on disk and reading that file with a function particular to CWA. That yields inconsistent results, however, as often the command output that gets written to file is simply `OK`.

---

### What I've tried

I've found and attempted many possible solutions. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287818/cause-less-to-exit-with-a-non-zero-status-code) question, specifically geared towards `less`, and was reliant on `less`'s `-K` argument. I attempted to adapt part of the solution with no success invoking `bash -c` and `trap`, though my implementation could have been incorrect. I also attempted something along the lines of `echo "Test" && false`, which returns `OK`, likely (in my mind) due to the first command returning with an exit code of 0 before evaluating `false`.

---

### Question restated

Is it possible to "coax" (so to speak) arbitrary utilities, particularly when invoked via `bash` or `sh`, into returning with an exit status of my choosing, or otherwise any non-0 exit status, and still have a given utility's output hit stdout/stderr?

Comment: You could do `(command_you_want && exit 1)` which will return an exit code of 1 if the command is successful, and leave it unchanged if it fails.

Comment: Since `echo "Test" && false` certainly does exit with a non-zero return code, something *else* about how the commands are running is getting in the way of achieving what you want (and it may not be what you think). How does it run the commands? Can you see what is actually executed? Is `bash -c 'echo "Test" && false` different, or is that what you already tried?

Comment: @MichaelHomer I have already tried `bash -c 'echo "Test" && false'` to no avail. Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding of how the above command would work is the `bash -c 'echo "test"` portion will return with an exit status of 0 before proceeding. The flow control operator `&&` actually relies on the the command to the left of it to return successful before proceeding. Do I have that right?

Comment: @StephenHarris Unfortunately, `echo` still returns with an exit code of 0 before moving on to `exit 1`. With a simplistic test of `(echo "Test" && echo $? && exit 1)` I get the output `Test 0` then it exits and sets `$?` to 1.

Comment: `echo test && false` (in every permutation posted so far) unequivocally exits 1. I don't know how this tool launches its programs, or how it decides what the result was, but something is not happening in the way you think it is.

Comment: `( echo test && exit 1)` is a single unit of execution and will always return 1. The 0 in the middle is not visible to the outside.   `echo test && echo $? && exit 1` is a _different_ program and is exposing the middle.

Comment: @MichaelHomer to quote [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/53577/linux-bash-syntax-meaning-of-and) superuser thread:

`

"&&" is used to chain commands together, such that the next command is run if and only if the preceding command exited without errors (or, more accurately, exits with a return code of 0).` That seems consistent with the behavior I've seen as well. It's certainly possible, if not likely, that something is happening that I don't understand, but my understanding of the `&&` short-circuit operator is that the first portion will return an exit code before evaluating more

Comment: @StephenHarris Thank you for the explanation. Since my simple test was flawed I'll try this in CWA and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Your understanding is not correct, which *is what everybody has been telling you this entire time* (so I'm not sure that there's much point in this comment either...). You would be better off trying to do something to diagnose and help yourself than searching for reasons that everyone else is wrong. Some questions were posed earlier in this thread that it would be useful to have answers to, but you haven't yet answered them.

Comment: Scott, it's not by accident that @Stephen Harris put those commands in round braces, it's run in a subshell and will always exit 1. I'm voting to stackoverflow, incase someone there knows anything about CWA.